# Read cookie in Go

Tags: go, cookies, client-server

I'm deploying a simple HTTP server and a simple HTTP client in Go. I tried to read the cookie value from the client without success (I receive an empty value) even if on the server the value that I see is set. How can I read the cookie value from the client side (i.e. to send the further requests by including the cookie that I received)?

**Server Code**

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "math/rand"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

var SERVER_PORT string = ":8080"

func setCookie(w http.ResponseWriter, username string){
    cookieValue := username + ":" + (username+strconv.Itoa(rand.Intn(100000000)))
    //expiration := time.Now().Add(365 * 24 * time.Hour)
    expiration := time.Now().Add(20 * time.Second)
    cookie := http.Cookie{Name:"SessionID", Value: cookieValue, Expires: expiration}
    http.SetCookie(w, &cookie)
    log.Print(cookie)
}

func sayHello(w http.ResponseWriter, r* http.Request) {
    username := r.URL.Path
    username = strings.TrimPrefix(username, "/")
    setCookie(w,username)
    message := "Hello " + username
    w.Write([]byte(message))
}

func ReadCookieServer(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    // read cookie
    var cookie,err = req.Cookie("SessionID")
    if err == nil {
        var cookievalue = cookie.Value
        w.Write([]byte(cookievalue))
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", sayHello)
    http.HandleFunc("/readcookie", ReadCookieServer)
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(SERVER_PORT, nil); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

**Client Code**

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    http "net/http"
)

var serverName string = "http://localhost"
var serverPort string = ":8080/"

func MakeRequest() {
    var username string = "blabla"
    resp, err := http.Get(serverName + serverPort + username)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    log.Println(string(body))
}

func Readcookie() {
    resp, err := http.Get(serverName + serverPort + "readcookie")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    log.Println(string(body))
}

func main() {
    MakeRequest()
    Readcookie()
}
```

Comment: @Flimzy When the client sends a request to the server, in this case the client should see the response and the cookie that he received from the server. I'm not understanding why I'm not able to see it client side.

Comment: What _do_ you see on the client? What did you expect to see instead?

Comment: You have your cookie in the first request `MakeRequest` of client code. The second request from client code `Readcookie` isn't provide any cookie for server.

Comment: @Flimzy I see just "Hello" + username. I would to see the cookie content that I received from the Server.

Comment: Where are you trying to read the cookie? All I see you doing is dumping the response body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to read the cookie from an HTTP request, you do it with the [`Cookies`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Response.Cookies) method.  Example:

```
func Readcookie() {
    resp, err := http.Get(serverName + serverPort + "readcookie")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    for _, cookie := range resp.Cookies() {
        if cookie.Name == "SessionID" {
            log.Println("Cookie: ", cookie.Value)
        }
    }
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    log.Println(string(body))
}
```

To achieve your larger goal, of session management across subsequent HTTP requests, simply instantiate a cookie jar on your HTTP client.  Example:

```
var client *http.Client

func init() {
    jar, err := cookiejar.New(&cookiejar.Options{PublicSuffixList: publicsuffix.List})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    client = &http.Client{Jar: jar}
}
```

Then use this client (rather than the default) for your subsequent requests:

```
func Readcookie() {
    resp, err := client.Get(serverName + serverPort + "readcookie")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    log.Println(string(body))
}
```

Comment: "doesn't work" isn't a useful problem statement. What problems did you encounter? What did you expect to see instead?

Comment: When I import "golang.org/x/net/publicsuffix" I receive an error during the import (probably it doesn't exist in the repo)

Comment: Did you try installing that package, then?

Answer (score -1):

First, check if the client is getting the cookie saved. Inspect the Browser > Storage > Cookies. if the client is getting the cookie, remember to enable in the client request the credentials.

```
fetch("http://example.com/data.json", {
       credentials: "include"
})
```

See more in: https://sabe.io/blog/javascript-pass-cookies-fetch-axios